# Why does the MOSFET in this circuit stay ON after a momentary trigger?

Tags: mosfet, switches

The MOSFET in this video turned ON and stayed ON after one momentary shorting of the 9V to the gate.
i always thought a MOSFET stays ON only while voltage is applied to it's gate.
at first i thought it may be a special type of MOSFET
but then i read in the description that "Any MOSFET can be used" 
What am i missing here?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MsEwDjl7P1Q

The circuit diagram from the video description [image]

Comment: The N Channel FET gate is basically a capacitor, once you charged it to 9v it just stayed there. You need a discharge resistance to ground. Realistically anything would work .... 1k to ground would be a good starting point. Or you could ensure you use a switch that connected the gate to ground (I'm assuming you are not using a switch in your experiment).

Comment: What does "voltage being applied" mean to you? In the case of a MOSFET, the voltage *stays* on the gate until it's taken off the gate.

Comment: @immibis when the voltage  was taken off the gate by opening the switch between the gate and 9V it meant to me, that it stopped being applied

Comment: @JackCreasey  So this is how a MOSFET really behaves ? i mean, i never encountered it in any circuit simulator.  could you share some reference ?

Comment: Unlike a transistor which is a current controlled amplifier, a Insulated gate FET is voltage driven (electric field). Once you charge the gat capacitance, it stays charged unless some means pf discharge exists. This same architecture is used to store bits in a memory device.

Comment: @soundslikefiziks this is absolutely how a MOSFET behaves. Switching it fast is all about managing gate charge - the charge on that capacitor - look at gate driver ICs, they are specialist parts and some of them can drive amps to move that charge fast (which reduces switching losses, increasing efficiency)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the equivalent circuit of the mosfet. The gate of the mosfet is equivalent to a capacitor.

[image]

So when you are applying a gate voltage with respect to source the capacitor will get charged,ie mosfet will get turned on.So the mosfet will be always on if you are not discharging the gate capacitor .

If you want to turn of the mosfet very fast ,you can supply a negative voltage with respect to source .Other wise you can put a pull down resistor (from gate to source)10k to discharge the capacitor.So it will turn of the mosfet immediately if you are not giving any voltage to the gate terminal

Answer (score 1):

The mosfet gate is a capacitor, it will hold voltage (a charge) for a long time, during this time the mosfet will be "on".

How long depends on how well insulated everything is how clean it is and the ambient relative humidity.

Get a mosfet and try it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The three pins on the left, and the "on" and "off" labels, could
imply that an SPDT (single pole double throw) toggle switch is to be attached there.   If
it were, the ON switch position connects the gate resistor to +9
and the OFF position connects the gate resistor to GND.
That would indeed turn the N-MOSFET on and off.

If,
instead of an SPDT switch, you substitute a  momentary
or SPST switch, the ON functions normally, but the OFF leaves
the gate of the MOSFET floating, and turnoff would be 
uncertain.  The charge on the MOSFET gate, like the charge on
a battery, stays until something changes it.